# Grails .findBy doesn't work with redis

Tags: grails, redis, grails-orm, grails-plugin

I have a very simple test case I am using to try to understand redis.  I did install-plugin redis-gorm.

Domain Object:

```
class BenchGroup {
  String groupName
  /*static mapWith = "redis"
  static mapping = {
    groupName(index:true)
  }*/
  static constraints = {
  }
}
```

Bootstrap Code:

```
def everyoneGroup = new BenchGroup(groupName:'everyoneGroup')
everyoneGroup.save()
if(everyoneGroup.hasErrors()){
  println everyoneGroup.errors
}
println everyoneGroup
def dammit = BenchGroup.findByGroupName('everyoneGroup')
println dammit
```

When I leave the redis map line commented it uses HSQL and outputs this:

```
stupidbenchmarks.BenchGroup : 2
stupidbenchmarks.BenchGroup : 2
```

When I  switch to redis it does this:

```
stupidbenchmarks.BenchGroup : 2
null
```

i.e.  .findBy doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate flushes before doing queries (in this case `findByGroupName`) but the NoSQL GORM Datastore implementations don't (yet) so I assume you just need a flush to push the saved instance to the datastore so the query picks it up:

```
everyoneGroup.save(flush: true)
```

Comment: Fixed it by uninstalling hibernate plug in and reinstalling 'redis-gorm' (also had 'redis' plugin installed so I got rid of that), then removing mapWith line from domain class.  Flushing does not seem to be necessary - code now works as intended without flush.